# 'Spoken English' Classes - is this title correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, indian-english

In India, they are in thousands, like mushrooms in rains. I really wonder whether the title is justified. In India, we have...

> Spoken English classes

These classes help non-natives speak English in a fluent way.

Is it the right title? Even strange is someone advising students:

> Learn ***spoken English*** OR
>  Join Spoken English classes.

***Spoken*** English? What do *natives* say about it?

But when it is *other than English,* I see other variant:

> *<del>Spoken Spanish Classes</del> Spanish Speaking Classes*

Comment: I don't find any of those to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both *Spoken* and *Speaking* sound a little awkward in the course title. Were I offering the course, I’d probably name it:

> Conversational English

There are plenty of courses that use some form of this, such as:

- [Introduction to Conversational English](https://alison.com/course/introduction-to-conversational-english)
- [Conversation English](https://www.britishcouncil.org.eg/en/english/courses-adults/conversation-english)
- [Conversational English in the Workplace for the Non-Native Speaker](https://www.utsa.edu/ee/ce/conversational-english.html)

---

<sub>Note 1: This isn’t to say that *Speaking English* couldn’t be a course title; this is just a personal preference of mine.</sub>
<sub>Note 2: The links are provided as examples only. Neither I nor ELL are endorsing those particular courses.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

"Spoken English class" is perfectly acceptable, and that's what I would call a class that deals with how English is spoken.

"Learn spoken English" is a perfectly acceptable sentence (in the imperative mood).

Answer (score 1):

- Spoken English Course(s)
- Spoken English Lesson(s)
- Spoken English Class(es)
- Spoken English Test(s)
- Spoken English Material(s)

More than a million combinations are possible and all of most will be correct and valid. Each will mean "*concerning or relating to spoken English*"

- English Speaking Class(es)
- English Speaking Lesson(s)
- English Speaking Course(s)
- English Speaking Practice
- English Speaking Skills
- English Speaking Tips
- English Speaking Basics

These are actually synonyms of the above and act in the same way.